# Redirect to profile page using facebook api

Tags: facebook

I need to create module for website which display feeds from client.

I had get feed from facebook using graph api of fb. But when i click on the profile name it says profile is not available.

This issue is occuring because facebook has moved to graph api 2 and in this version user is returned on basis on app which is diffrent from actual user id.

So if i need to redirect page from the website. How can i implement this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Redirecting to 

https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{user-id}/

instead of 

https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id={user-id}

solve my issue.

Thank You. @Tobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `link` field of the `User` object like this:

```
/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,link
```

The result will be similar to the following:

```
{
  "id": "10152055263451244234", 
  "first_name": "TheFirstName", 
  "last_name": "TheLastName", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10152055263451244234/"
}
```

Or, if you already have a app-scoped user_id, you can construct the link manually by

```
"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/" + {user_id} + "/"
```

Comment: But i'm getting json for user feed is there any direct way?

Comment: What do you mean with direct? Graph API output is always in JSON format.

Comment: In graph api 1 we can redirect from browser to user page using following 
facebook.com/profile.php?id={user-id} where user id is returned in json.

But in graph api 2 app spcoped user id has introduced because of which this is not working. Now i have used following to redirect to user profile page.
facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id{user-id} 
here user id app scoped user id returned in JSON.

Thank You